# Turn on Normal F Keys on Matias Tactile Pro (FK302) on OSX/iMac

Tags: macos, keyboard

The F keys on the Tactile Pro are set to trigger the Apple special functions (Dashboard, Brightness Control, Spaces, etc.).

Under Keyboard System Preferences, there is no option to switch these back to normal F key usage as there is on Apple laptops.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Preferences does not have an overall setting to turn on/off special use of the F keys. This appears on my MacBook Pro, but doesn't on my iMac for some reason.

At the same time, the Tactile Pro doesn't have an 'Fn' key, as normal Apple keyboards do. (This is used to override any special use of the F keys to their normal F functions.)

What can be done instead is to remove the override for each function key individually. I needed the F8 key, which was mapped to Spaces. I unmapped it, problem solved.